# Dynamic PHP string as MySQL table name

Tags: php, mysqli

I have mySQL tables namely q1 , q2 , q3 and so on....

now the following code is in loop with $n increasing with every step of loop.

```
$table = "q".$n;
$query="SELECT MAX(QNO) AS max2 FROM '$table'";
$q=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db));
$max2 = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
```

This gives me an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"q1"' at line 1

How to solve this problem and putting new name of table everytime in the query?

Comment: You need to quote tables & column names with backticks, not single quotes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: Did you try without the single quotes around the table name?

Comment: If the value for `$n` originates from user input, be sure to validate it before using it in `$table`. It looks like you are creating quarters `q1, q2, q3, q4` so that it is an integer, and in the range 1-4. If it is strictly created in code by literal ints, don't worry about validating it as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$query="SELECT MAX(QNO) AS max2 FROM $table";` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
'$table'
```

into

```
`$table`
```

in the query:

```
"SELECT MAX(QNO) AS max2 FROM '$table'";
```

so it looks like:

```
"SELECT MAX(QNO) AS max2 FROM `$table`";
```